# Catch close/unload event in Actionscript/Flex application

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, air

This questin might sound very, very simplistic, yet I have not been able to find an answer, neither on official documentation nor official forums or anywhere.

I am just looking for the event fired when the user closes the application. This event MUST exist, Flash has been around for 11 versions now, I could not imagine there is no such thing...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Since you're looking for an AIR specific solution; you'll want to take listen for the [closing](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/WindowedApplication.html#event%3aclosing) event on your main application tag ( WindowedApplication).

Conceptually something like this:

```
<s:WindowedApplication closing="onClosing(event)">
 <fx:Script>
   public function onClosing(event:Event):void{
     // execute code here
   }
 </fx:Script>

</s:WindowedApplication>
```

You may also examine the [close event](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/WindowedApplication.html#event%3aclose) on the same class, or the [exiting](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeApplication.html#event%3aexiting) event on the NativeWindow class.  You can access the NativeWindow using something like this:

```
<s:WindowedApplication creationCompete="onCreationComplete(event)">
 <fx:Script>
   public function onCreationComplete(event:Event):void{
     this.addEventListener('exiting',onExiting);
   }
   public function onExiting(event:Event):void{
     // execute code here
   }
 </fx:Script>

</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. I didn't know I had to be THIS specific: your solution does work when the container is a WindowedApplication. Unfortunately, due to Adobe specification regarding TV app, I have to use Application instead. And then none of your solutions work.

Comment: @cystack I'm surprised at how many important details you've left out of the original question.  You really should edit your question to specify that you are building an AIR for TV app.  AIR for TV is based off AIR 2.5; which is less than a year old.  You're in a very different situation than your complaint about 11 versions of Flash would have us believe.

Answer (score 2):

Well, think about it for a minute. You're asking for an event, to be fired, when the application closes... so, what fires the event, and what's going to handle it? The application? But it just closed. You could of course, do something in javascript and check the status of the flash embed, but even that isn't always going to work depending on how the flash player is being unloaded (E.G. the user closes their browser). Furthermore, what happens if the user kills the flash sandbox or browser? There's no way to send an event from a terminated application.

Ultimately I'd take a very close look at exactly what it is you're trying to accomplish and try to figure out a better way of doing it. If you're worried about a remote resource like a server cleaning up some resources, you might want to implement a keepalive signal and just do your cleanup when you stop receiving it.

Comment: I can't take advantage of browser tools because I am doing an AIR application. Be it on the desktop (Alt-F4-like action) or on TV (very TV dependant), I want to clean up resources on the serverside. A keepalive signal really sounds like overkill, and I don't even think I have access to the server's code :/ so your analysis is correct, but my problem is still the same :)

Comment: @cystack For the record AIR has not been around for 11 versions. If you're looking for an AIR specific answer, you should specify that as part of your question; and perhaps remove your complaints about Flash's age.

Comment: I +1 this because it was a valiant attempt at answering a non-specific question.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at [Closing event](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/reference/html/flash/events/Event.html#CLOSING) 
You can attach event listener to it and in callback function use prevent default so window doesn't get closed and you can run your logic. After that by calling close() function, you can close your window.

So you know for sure your what you want to run at time of closing get executed successfully.

Comment: I have done similar thing in JavaScript AIR application and is working correctly.
Closing event object `air.Event.CLOSING`
close function `window.nativeWindow.close()`